# Customer voice survey embed code into a marketing email in dynamics 365

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, html-email, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I try to make a customer voice survey, after i have made my survey, i want to add it into a marketing email. On the send tab inside customre voice i get options: Generate a direct link or code to the survey - embeded code, link or qr code.

I chose embede code, and get this code:

```
<script src="https://fefweafewacdnweu.azureedge.net/vdvwvwvwu/Embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="https://fefweafewacdnweu.azureedge.net/fefweafewacdnweu/Embed.css" /><script type = "text/javascript" >function renderSurvey(parentElementId,FirstName, LastName, locale){var se = new SurveyEmbed("iu1XS1e8Q0GCKbaMfefweafewacdnweuSF10DpJRUMzI3MzRKWDFRTEg5M1BGRUZMME9FNzc3NS4u","https://customervoice.microsoft.com/","https://fefweafewacdnweu.azureedge.net/fefweafewacdnweu/","true");var context = {"First Name": FirstName,"Last Name": LastName,"locale": locale,};se.renderInline(parentElementId, context);}</script>
```

> type="text/css"href="https://fefweafewacdnweu.azureedge.net/fefweafewacdnweu/Embed.css"
> />function
> renderSurvey(parentElementId,FirstName, LastName, locale){var se = new
> SurveyEmbed("iu1XS1e8Q0GCKbaMfefweafewacdnweuSF10DpJRUMzI3MzRKWDFRTEg5M1BGRUZMME9FNzc3NS4u","https://customervoice.microsoft.com/","https://fefweafewacdnweu.azureedge.net/fefweafewacdnweu/","true");var
> context = {"First Name": FirstName,"Last Name": LastName,"locale":
> locale,};se.renderInline(parentElementId, context);}

Then i follow this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dynamics365/customer-voice/embed-web-page

That says i need to add also this code something like this:

```
<div id="surveyDiv" style="height: 400px">
     <script>
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      renderSurvey("surveyDiv");
        }, false);
      </script>
</div>
```

Then i go over to my marketing email, and try to past this codes inside "html" code in the email, but then it stops. I do not get any data innside, i think the marketing "html" code will not take the script, because when i try to test, and look at the marketing email code again, the scripts are gone.

Hopes this give a good overview over what i try to do. Does anybody see something i do not see?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to embed a QR code into an email body? I'm not sure I'm following what you're trying to do here. Why not just distribute the survey automatically through customer voice or through power automate?

Comment: Hi. No, i want to embed the NPS score inside an marketing email. Like this image: https://stripo-cdn.stripo.email/photos/shares/Blog//Survey-Invitation-Email.png I know i can send the survey from customer voice, but we have premade templates and email we want to add this to, thats is why i want to try to do it this why. But maybe it cant be done.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think the script inside the div should be there. Try placing this part outside of the div:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        renderSurvey("surveyDiv");
    }, false);
</script>
```